# Console won't power off on PowerPC with Debian

Tags: debian, power-management, powerpc

I installed Debian 6.0 on a Power Mac G5. First it would boot to a blank screen but I fixed that by blacklisting nouveau as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19722/debian-ppc-on-powermac-g5-boots-to-blank-screen).

Now the monitor will never turn off. It's a server so I'll mostly ssh into it and I want the monitor to power down after a very short time.

I have no xserver installed and just use the console. I've tried modifying `/etc/kbd/config` but that didn't work. I also tried installing `console-tools` and modifying `/etc/console-tools/config` but that didn't work. Then I tried using `setterm` and that didn't work. I even tried using console codes to blank the screen, but that didn't work either.

Does anyone know how I get control of the power saving modes for this console?

Comment: Check out `vbetool`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44809/tty-console-disable-monitor

Comment: I'll look into this. For some reason I thought `vbetool` was X related but it appears I was wrong about that.

Comment: Interesting. `vbetool` package doesn't exist for ppc architechture - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=285361.

Comment: I think that vbetool is x86-specific (its manpage references "real mode" and BIOS, for example).

Answer (score 0):

I would use pbbuttonsd / pommed / pmud for suspend / hibernate and shutdown control.